# can google assistant be used to create a community events calendar

Tags: actions-on-google

Can a community use google assistant to list a community events calendar?  Ok Google what is happening in my community today?  or OK Google what is happening at the city park this weekend?

I have seen many links to how to point google assistant to my own personal calendar, but no way to say use google sheet as the data for the communities upcoming events.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

You cannot just update a spreadsheet and have the Google Assistant give community events based on this change, any more than you can do so and have Google Search give community events directly in response to a search.

Although Google is increasingly scraping websites, particularly AMP enabled websites, for direct answers to questions, this isn't the sort of question that they're currently indexing for. So there is no way to guarantee that the information is currently indexed to answer a question such as this.

*However...*

You can certainly create an Action using the [Actions on Google SDK](https://developers.google.com/actions/) that can read a spreadsheet to answer community questions. This is the equivalent of your community setting up a website that people would go visit to see the community calendar, and residents could look things up by invoking the "Town of Wherever" Action with a phrase such as "Hey Google, ask Town of Wherever what is happening in the park".

Building such an Action would require you to [write a webhook](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment) that accepts JSON from the Assistant, lookup the information you want using the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) or something similar, and then returning JSON with the response.

Comment: I am not looking to answer any community questions, I am looking to set up a way for someone to say   Ok Google, whats happening in my town tonight?  And Google assistant will return a list of things to do tonight in your town.

Comment: I've clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks for revising your answer. My question still remains, can I use a google sheet as the basis for creating a community events calendar type of assistant, so some one can say ok google what’s happening near me tonight or where is there live music tonight or what is happening at the community center tonight. Or other local venue.

Comment: I've clarified further, I hope.

Comment: Thanks. Do I use the quiz template or what?  If someone has a link to a tutorial, please share.